# How can I access table values in a SAS user defined function?

Tags: sql, sas

I am creating a function to return the Monthly Working Day Number in SAS EG. Weekends I can find using weekday() but I also need to take bank holidays into account. We have a table of bank holidays and I have tried several ways to get the function to be able to read the Bank Holidays table and return the number of bank holidays that have passed in the current month.

Essentially I need a way to execute SQL from within the function and return 2 values from the SQL Select statement. I have the SQL which uses Select into, which works. How do I get those values back to the code in the function?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and code that you have? This should be possible with a little SQL. At the very least, this could be turned into a macro function. Also, have you looked into the `holiday` and `holidaycount` functions to see if they cover all of your holidays?

Comment: Also, look into the `eventds` system option.

Answer (score 5):

Proc FCMP does not have a feature to perform SQL queries.

You can use the FCMP function READ_ARRAY() to pull a data set column into your custom function.

Example:

```
proc fcmp outlib = work.so.example;

   function example() ;
     array nvalues[100, 5] / nosymbols;
     rc = read_array('sashelp.class', nvalues, 'age', 'weight');

     put nvalues;

     return (0);
   endsub;

run;

options cmplib=work.so;

data _null_;;
  z = example();
  put z=;
run;
```

will log the age and weights from sashelp.class

```
14 112.5 13 84 13 98 14 102.5 14 102.5 12 83 12 84.5 15 112.5 13 84 12 99.5 11 50.5 14 90 12 77
15 112 16 150 12 128 15 133 11 85 15 112
z=0
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I'll check it now...

Comment: This is my preferred option. Because I have a fairly small dataset creating an array of the results looks like the quickest solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get PROC FCMP to run a macro, and return a value (or values) back to the FCMP function. The macro runs completely independently from where it's called in the code, so you can run SQL inside a datastep function for example.

This is known as a "macro-function-sandwich", several SAS SUGI papers cover it in more detail.

A very powerful construct...

```
%MACRO FCMP_BANKHOL ;
  /* startDT and endDT are passed in from FCMP, and NUM_BH is passed back */
  %LET NUM_BH = -1 ; /* default value if SQL fails */
  proc sql noprint ;
    select count(1) into :NUM_BH
    from work.bankhols
    where Date between &startDT and &endDT
    ;
  quit ;
%MEND ;

options cmplib=work.helpers ;
proc fcmp outlib=work.helpers.bankhol ;
  function getBankHols(startDT, endDT) ;
    rc = run_macro('FCMP_BANKHOL',startDT, endDT, NUM_BH) ;
    return (NUM_BH) ;
  endsub ;
quit ;

data bankhols ;
  input Date : date9. ;
  format Date date9. ;
datalines ;
25DEC2022
26DEC2022
01JAN2023
;
run ;

/* Example usage */
data _null_ ;
  num_bh = getBankHols('01jan2023'd,'31jan2023'd) ;
  put num_bh= ;

  dtstart = '01dec2022'd ;
  dtend   = '31dec2022'd ;
  num_bh = getBankHols(dtstart, dtend) ;
  put num_bh= ;  
run ;

/* Or via %SYSFUNC ... */
%LET NUM_BH = %SYSFUNC(getBankHols('01jan2023'd,'31jan2023'd)) ;
%PUT &NUM_BH ;
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `NOPRINT` option when using `INTO :MACVAR` syntax.  Do you think *behind the scenes* SAS has shared code between `run_macro()` and `dosubL()` ?

Comment: This looks very useful, and I've modified it to suit my needs, keeping the principles, but it seems to be running the macro code after returning the result of the function, meaning that I'm not getting the right result. I can see that the SQL works and that the function appears to work, but the macro execution is delayed. Is there a way to fix that? I can include the SAS log if that helps.